# Powershell Windows-1251 Encoding

Tags: powershell, cyrillic

When I try to read a file with Russian encoding
(Example):

```
$CommentChar = @(";")
$commentRegex = "^\s*([$($CommentChar -join '')].*)$"
switch -regex -file .\myinifile.ini {
$commentRegex {
$value = $matches[1]
Write-host "$value"
}
}
```

Instead of Russian characters, I get that:
�������� ����, 0 - ���������

How can I change the encoding to Windows 1251 ?

Comment: Encoding of reading the file, or encoding of writing to the console?

Comment: Encoding of reading the file

Comment: whats your **System Locale** set to?

Comment: You might want to switch to separately reading the file using Get-Content, then you can pass the encoding with `-Encoding Windows-1251`

Comment: get-help Get-content ....   [-Encoding {Unknown | String | Unicode | Byte | BigEndianUnicode | UTF8 | UTF7 | UTF32 | Ascii | Default | Oem | BigEndianUTF32}]   - there is no encoding 1251

Comment: System Locale: ru;Russian

Answer (score 1):

You can read a file with encoding codepage 1251 like below:

```
# for .Net methods, you need absolute paths
$file = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($pwd, '.\myinifile.ini'))

# get the 1251 encoding object
$cyrillicEnc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("windows-1251")
# read all lines in an array
$contents = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($file, $cyrillicEnc)

# and loop over them using your regex
$CommentChar  = ";"
$commentRegex = "^\s*([$($CommentChar -join '')].*)$"
foreach ($line in $contents) {
    if ($line -match $commentRegex) { Write-Host $matches[1] }
}
```

Assuming your file looks anything like this:

```
Доброе утро
  ; Рад познакомиться с тобой
Как дела?
```

The result of the above code would be

```
; Рад познакомиться с тобой
```